# RISC-V exception interpretation

Tags: riscv

I started working with MCU based on Nuclei (RISC-V) recently. Yesterday i got and exception with **mdcause** register value **0x38000001**. Unfortunately I haven't found any information how to interpret it. Any help?

Comment: What is `mcause` for that exception?

Comment: https://doc.nucleisys.com/nuclei_spec/isa/core_csr.html#mdcause